# Storyboard Zoom In/Out Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: xcode4

What shortcut key combination can I use in Xcode to zoom in and out? Yes, I know this is a silly question but a Google search didn't give me any result. Even the Xcode keyboard shortcuts didn't give me much info. Maybe I must ask for a better updated keyboard shortcut doc for Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this

Zoom Out = <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>

Zoom In = <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>

This worked for me!

Comment: This is just ridiculous. Standard zoom on any other app is command++/- which isn't used in Xcode. I swear, Apple wants to give me carpal tunnel.

Comment: If only there was some way to change it...  Seriously, though, they're bound in the doc editor.  But, it's pretty easy to change hotkeys.

Comment: @JonnyRamos xcode is ridiculous in general. By default, Tab doesn't indent selected blocks of code? What developer thinks "Hey, I want to replace this entire block of code with a tab character"? Line numbers aren't enabled by default either.

Comment: @JonnyRamos after long time they heard you. From Xcode version 7.0.1 it is Command Key with + OR -

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Double click on empty screen is zooming out and in. Dont know how to zoomin further

Answer (score 61):

You can also **double click with mouse** on empty area of storyboard. First time will zoom out, second time - zoom in. Sometimes it's easier than use difficult hotkey.

Comment: You saved my fingers!

Comment: **right click with mouse** on empty area brings further options! Thanks for letting me find "zoom" again.

Answer (score 8):

From Mouse or Trackpad -> Right Click will show you options. Hope this will help[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just figured this out -.- 
Make sure you're using a story board.
Then you can go to editor -> canvas -> zoom
Shortcuts are alt, command { and alt, command }

Answer (score 4):

Go to

**`System preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts`**

Select App Shortcuts
Click on Plus icon (+)

[image: Custom Zoom in and zoom out shortcuts]

[image: Manually add keyboard shortcut]

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7, the shortcuts have changed to the following:

- **Zooming out   :** <kbd>cmd (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>
- **Zooming In    :** <kbd>cmd (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>
- **Normal (100%) :** <kbd>cmd (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl (^)</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If you have a trackpad you can also pinch to zoom in/out (but yeah, that's not a "keyboard shortcut" :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from Rohit works, but the menu option simply says Command+Alt+{ and Command+Alt+} on XCode 5, i.e. Alt is not necessary. 
Funny thing is other SO answers said zoom was NOT possible, maybe added in later Xcode 4x or 5?

Apple loves whitespace and wide margins, but if you have more than a few screens, zooming is absolutely essential even on 4k displays!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trackpad, you can click on the storyboard and single tap with two fingers to get a menu of zoom options.

**Note:** if you don't have the tap with two finger gesture setup, you can go to System Preferences > Trackpad > Point & Click. Then change Secondary click to "Click or tap with two fingers"

Answer (score 0):

In turkish keyboard
cmd + :  (zoom in)
cmd + -  (zoom out)