# How to zoom in Xcode on a code window

Tags: ios, xcode, shortcut

How do you zoom in to see code better in xcode.  I'm looking for a shortcut, and not to change the projects display preferences. Also using CTRL + two fingers on mouse is not suitable as I'm using a multi-monitor set up and that zooms both monitors.  I only want to zoom in on the code text.  I found another solution here that allows zooming on the storyboard : [Storyboard Zoom In/Out Keyboard Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703302/storyboard-zoom-in-out-keyboard-shortcut)  but this doesn't work on any of the code files.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the best way doing it, just go to XCode-> Preference-> Fonts and Colors-> click on the T logo under the font.

Comment: Hi Bejibun thanks - but I was hoping for a shortcut.  It's not really practical to constantly change the preferences.  Most text editors provide the ability to either mouse zoom or use a keyboard shortcut to increase the font size.  I find it strange that XCode doesn't

Comment: System Prefs -> Accessibility -> Zoom

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your response. But that is a system wide preference and yes it does allow me to zoom, but I'm using two monitors and it zooms both monitors.  What I want to do is zoom the text on the active window only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I needed to install a plugin to have the functionality - This is the plugin https://github.com/zats/AdjustFontSize-Xcode-Plugin

Comment: this is outdated solution, as it is not working now with Xcode 8

Answer (score 39):

For Xcode 9 and above:

- Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to increase text size
- Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease text size

Comment: Works for XCode 10.0+ also

Answer (score 23):

I'm using xcode 7:
1. Xcode menu-> Preferences.
2. Choose the tab Fonts & Colors.
3. Choose theme on the left side.
4. On the right side cmd+A to choose all type of source.
5. In font field, click to T icon.
6. Choose a font size that you want to set.

Answer (score 4):

On my machine (Xcode 14.2, macOS 13.2.1, Turkish-Q keyboard) the shortcuts to change font size is like that:

To increase: `⌘:`

To decrease: `⌘-`

You can see the shortcuts by navigating:

- Menu bar
- Editor
- Font Size [somewhere on the middle]

Comment: Many keyboards use Cmd-plus to increase the font. I wonder if Cmd-colon is specific to the Turkish-Q keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Click two times on the screen and drag left or right

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 7.2 you can change the font size and colors on Xcode menu (preferences).

Answer (score 0):

**Option (⌥ alt) + mouse scroll wheel** works for Xcode13.2.1 on mac to zoom in/out in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings, keyboard, keyboard shortcuts,app shortcuts

There write menu name as Increase and select what ever shortcut you want to use

Comment: Why not simply use Cmd-plus and Cmd-minus? It's built into Xcode. No need to create any app shortcuts.